# Extracting jansson JSON data

Tags: c, json

I am using the C jansson library http://www.digip.org/jansson/

It's quite easy to use https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/tutorial.html#the-program

But I cannot get a simple `int` out of my JSON string. I can successfully receive and `load` a string of JSON (as in I get no errors, nothing is `null`) but when I use the jansson `get` functions to get an `int`, my `int` is always 0 even though using steps and breakpoints, the jansson function process an in is *not* returning 0.

The JSON string looks like this:

```
{"type":3}
```

Here is the code:

```
static void foo(json_t *jsonRoot) {
    // json root is error checked even before this, and is not null
    if (jsonRoot == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Trying to get type = 3
    json_t *j_type;
    int type = 0;

    j_type = json_object_get(jsonRoot, "type");
    if (!json_is_integer(j_type)) {
        printf("Not an int!\n");
        return;
    } else {
        // I get in to the else
        // json_integer_value has a its own internal check and 
        // will return 0 if the value is not an int, but it is not 
        // returning 0. It is running the macro json_to_integer(json)->value
        type = json_integer_value(j_type);
    }

    printf("type is %d\n", type);
    // type is 0
}
```

Comment: it work fine to me. try at caller side `char text[] = "{\"type\":3}";
 json_error_t error;
 json_t *root;

 root = json_loads(text, 0, &error);
 if(!root){
  fprintf(stderr, "error : root\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "error : on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
  exit(1);
 }
 foo(root);`

Comment: Tried this, still get 0. Going nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was with strtoll. I had to redefine it.